# Implementing pallet_contracts into node

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-contracts

I'm trying to implement pallet_contracts into my node, but that results in an error. I don't get why I'm getting this error and what I'm supposed to do with it.

```
    Checking pallet-contracts v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git?tag=polkadot-v1.6.0#481165d9)
   Compiling node-icv-runtime v1.1.0-dev (/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/polkadot-hackathon-24q1/node/runtime)
error[E0449]: visibility qualifiers are not permitted here
    --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/481165d/substrate/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs:1247:3
     |
1247 |         environmental!(executing_contract: bool);
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: trait items always share the visibility of their trait
     = note: this error originates in the macro `environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0449`.
error: could not compile `pallet-contracts` (lib) due to 3 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-icv-runtime v1.1.0-dev (/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/polkadot-hackathon-24q1/node/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/polkadot-hackathon-24q1/node/target/release/build/node-icv-runtime-3e923a035f42d14e/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: env -u CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS CARGO_TARGET_DIR="/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/polkadot-hackathon-24q1/node/target/release/wbuild/node-icv-runtime/target" RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/arjanvaneersel/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/polkadot-hackathon-24q1/node/target/release/wbuild/node-icv-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release" "-Z" "build-std"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.77.0-nightly (25f8d01fd 2024-01-18)


  --- stderr
     Compiling pallet-contracts v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git?tag=polkadot-v1.6.0#481165d9)
  warning: unstable feature specified for `-Ctarget-feature`: `sign-ext`
    |
    = note: this feature is not stably supported; its behavior can change in the future

  warning: `pallet-template` (lib) generated 1 warning
  error[E0449]: visibility qualifiers are not permitted here
      --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/481165d/substrate/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs:1247:3
       |
  1247 |         environmental!(executing_contract: bool);
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       |
       = note: trait items always share the visibility of their trait
       = note: this error originates in the macro `environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0449`.
  error: could not compile `pallet-contracts` (lib) due to 3 previous errors
  thread 'main' panicked at /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/481165d/substrate/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:822:37:
  Copying the bloaty file to the project dir.: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Here relevant snippets of my runtime's Cargo.toml:

```
...
# Additional Dependencies
pallet-nfts = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", tag = "polkadot-v1.6.0", default-features = false }
pallet-identity = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", tag = "polkadot-v1.6.0", default-features = false }
pallet-contracts = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", tag = "polkadot-v1.6.0", default-features = false }

# Local Dependencies
pallet-template = { path = "../pallets/template", default-features = false }

...

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    ...
    "pallet-contracts/std",
    ...

]
runtime-benchmarks = [
    ...
    "pallet-contracts/runtime-benchmarks",
    ...

]
try-runtime = [
    ...
    "pallet-contracts/try-runtime",
    ...
]
```

Here from lib.rs:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
// `construct_runtime!` does a lot of recursion and requires us to increase the limit to 256.
#![recursion_limit = "256"]

...

parameter_types! {
    pub Schedule: pallet_contracts::Schedule<Runtime> = Default::default();
    pub CodeHashLockupDepositPercent: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(30);
}

/// Configure pallet_contracts.
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    /// The safest default is to allow no calls at all.
    ///
    /// Runtimes should whitelist dispatchables that are allowed to be called from contracts
    /// and make sure they are stable. Dispatchables exposed to contracts are not allowed to
    /// change because that would break already deployed contracts. The `Call` structure itself
    /// is not allowed to change the indices of existing pallets, too.
    type CallFilter = Nothing;
    type DepositPerItem = dynamic_params::contracts::DepositPerItem;
    type DepositPerByte = dynamic_params::contracts::DepositPerByte;
    type DefaultDepositLimit = dynamic_params::contracts::DefaultDepositLimit;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 5];
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
    type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 123 * 1024 }>;
    type MaxStorageKeyLen = ConstU32<128>;
    type UnsafeUnstableInterface = ConstBool<false>;
    type MaxDebugBufferLen = ConstU32<{ 2 * 1024 * 1024 }>;
    type RuntimeHoldReason = RuntimeHoldReason;
    #[cfg(not(feature = "runtime-benchmarks"))]
    type Migrations = ();
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    type Migrations = pallet_contracts::migration::codegen::BenchMigrations;
    type MaxDelegateDependencies = ConstU32<32>;
    type CodeHashLockupDepositPercent = CodeHashLockupDepositPercent;
    type Debug = ();
    type Environment = ();
    type Xcm = ();
}

...

// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
construct_runtime!(
    pub struct Runtime {
        System: frame_system,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Aura: pallet_aura,
        Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        Sudo: pallet_sudo,
        Nfts: pallet_nfts,
        Identity: pallet_identity,
        Contracts: pallet_contracts,
        // Include the custom logic from the pallet-template in the runtime.
        TemplateModule: pallet_template,
    }
);

...

#[allow(unused_parens)]
type Migrations = (pallet_contracts::Migration<Runtime>);

...

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benches {
    define_benchmarks!(
        [frame_benchmarking, BaselineBench::<Runtime>]
        [frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>]
        [pallet_balances, Balances]
        [pallet_contracts, Contracts]
        [pallet_identity, Identity]
        [pallet_nfts, Nfts]
        [pallet_timestamp, Timestamp]
        [pallet_sudo, Sudo]
        [pallet_template, TemplateModule]
    );
}

...

impl pallet_contracts::ContractsApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash, EventRecord> for Runtime
    {
        fn call(
            origin: AccountId,
            dest: AccountId,
            value: Balance,
            gas_limit: Option<Weight>,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            input_data: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::ContractExecResult<Balance, EventRecord> {
            let gas_limit = gas_limit.unwrap_or(RuntimeBlockWeights::get().max_block);
            Contracts::bare_call(
                origin,
                dest,
                value,
                gas_limit,
                storage_deposit_limit,
                input_data,
                pallet_contracts::DebugInfo::UnsafeDebug,
                pallet_contracts::CollectEvents::UnsafeCollect,
                pallet_contracts::Determinism::Enforced,
            )
        }

        fn instantiate(
            origin: AccountId,
            value: Balance,
            gas_limit: Option<Weight>,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            code: pallet_contracts::Code<Hash>,
            data: Vec<u8>,
            salt: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::ContractInstantiateResult<AccountId, Balance, EventRecord>
        {
            let gas_limit = gas_limit.unwrap_or(RuntimeBlockWeights::get().max_block);
            Contracts::bare_instantiate(
                origin,
                value,
                gas_limit,
                storage_deposit_limit,
                code,
                data,
                salt,
                pallet_contracts::DebugInfo::UnsafeDebug,
                pallet_contracts::CollectEvents::UnsafeCollect,
            )
        }

        fn upload_code(
            origin: AccountId,
            code: Vec<u8>,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            determinism: pallet_contracts::Determinism,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::CodeUploadResult<Hash, Balance>
        {
            Contracts::bare_upload_code(
                origin,
                code,
                storage_deposit_limit,
                determinism,
            )
        }

        fn get_storage(
            address: AccountId,
            key: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::GetStorageResult {
            Contracts::get_storage(
                address,
                key
            )
        }
    }

...
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is some 'regression' introduced by recent nightly toolchains; fix is there: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/2986